# render.canvas.getContext('2d') is coming null in matter.js, even though render.canvas is getting the canvas properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, rendering, matter.js

In my matter.js project, am using matter-js 0.19.0 by @liabru 
In line 8677, we have:

```
render.context = render.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

which comes to "null". 
In line 8676, ie a line before in:

```
render.canvas = render.canvas || _createCanvas(render.options.width, render.options.height);
```

I am getting the canvas fine. 
This problem is not there if I use a new canvas, but the project already has a canvas and a framework based on that, and I'm supposed to use that only instead of a new canvas.

And because of this coming null, there is no drawing and hence the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'globalCompositeOperation')
```

Comment: `getContext('2d')` will return `null` [if the requested context differs from the first contextType requested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#return_value). Is it possible that the project is already using e.g. a webgl context on that canvas?

Comment: @motto Yes, the project does uses 2d and/or webgl. But I shouldn't alter it.

Comment: Being that as it may, you can't have multiple contexts on the same canvas. [See previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55977948/21146235). You can render a separate canvas with your 2d context on top of (or below) the canvas with a webgl context, using transparency/compositing as appropriate.

Comment: @motto Yes I have tried on a new canvas and it works fine, but I intend to do in same canvas. Doesn't matter.js allows to use the existing context instead of new context?

Comment: A canvas can only have one context. If there's an existing 2d context on the canvas then matter.js will re-use that. If there's an existing non-2d context (such as a webgl context) then it will get `null` instead of a 2d context, and you will get TypeErrors about not being able to set properties of `null`. This is an intentional and inherent limit of canvases, and the way around it is to create a separate canvas.

Answer (score -1):

Check that the canvas element exists in the HTML document and ensure that the canvas element has dimensions: getContext('2d') method will return null if the canvas element has a width or height of 0.

Comment: Nope, it won't.