# single channel image from HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata

I want to reduce the dimensions of the image obtained from a canvas

```js
const imgData = this.ctx.getImageData(
  0,
  0,
  280,
  280
);
const img_arr = new ImageData(imgData.data, imgData.width, imgData.height);
// ImageData { width: 280, height: 280, data: Uint8ClampedArray(313600) }
console.log(img_arr);
```

> length 313600 = 280 x 280 x 4 (RGBA)

Is there a way to obtain single chanel image directly rather than looping the rgba image array??

```js
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
  grayImgData.data[cnt] = imgData.data[i];
cnt+=1;
}
```

Comment: Not with the 2d context. WebGL has a LUMINANCE texture format that would probably fit your needs though. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73322880/3702797 (I'm kind of hesitating to mark your question as a duplicate btw, let me know if it does indeed answer your question)

Comment: @Kaiido `WebGL` is not supported by my browsers on Ubuntu.

Comment: Then you're out of luck.

Comment: @Kaiido, It was a mistake, [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973458) the reason.

Comment: @Kaiido "*let me know if it does indeed answer your question*", actually it **doesn't**, as that answer doesn't explain how to `getImageData()` with **LUMINANCE**!